# VoiceOver not reading UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, voiceover

We have some UIViews.  I have isAccessibilityElement set to YES and gave it an accessibility label.  If I tap on the item, VoiceOver reads the item.  But if I am doing two-finger swipes to read the whole screen, it skips over it.  What step am I missing to add that to the two-swipe action?

Comment: What traits do you have set?  Have you tried setting it as StaticText perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Note that its better to evaluate the view using a one finger swipe left/right than the two-finger swipe down to read the whole view.

If you swipe right/left with one finger and the element still isn't being focused by VoiceOver and you have set isAccessibilityElement=YES, its possible that the element is appearing later in the list of accessibility elements that VoiceOver holds.

Try creating an accessibilityContainer on your containing element and subclass a method called accessibilityElements. Return an array of your accessibilityElements for the container view in the order you want VoiceOver to read them. For more info on this technique, see:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAccessibilityContainer_Protocol/index.html